# About Mooby's in Clerks II

Tags: plot-explanation, clerks-ii

This is about Clerks II. When Jay said "You knocked up the guy who own Mooby's?" who was he referring to? Because in Dogma, the boss of Mooby's has already been killed by Matt Damon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canon quote is :

> **Randal Graves:** *Oh, yeah, it's my fault your life's f#cked up.* "**I'm the engaged guy who knocked up my boss!**"
>
> **Jay:** [amazed] *You knocked up the guy who owns Mooby's?*

In this instance, Randall is referring to the manager of their branch of Mooby's (Becky) as their boss rather than the guy who ultimately owns the Mooby's franchise. Jay is too dumb/stoned to realise this, hence his amazement.

Earlier in the film, we see the line:

> **Becky:** ***I'm pregnant, Dante.***

Comment: I know what Randal means . But how do Jay know the one who owns mooby's is a guy ? Because in Dogma, the boss of Mooby's has already been killed by Matt Damon. Or he's just too dumb that he say anything that comes to his mind ?

Comment: @Alan - The latter. Randall is a misogynist and instantly assumes that their boss is a man.